# php: getting rid of ?p= query in url?

Tags: php, url

hey guys, i'm not looking for a mod_rewrite thing or anything related.
i'm just not sure if this is possible or not?

i'm using if(isset($_GET['p'])) … to check if ?p=something is set in my url, if not $foo = "bar"; if a ?p= is set e.g. ?p=something  –> $foo = "something". got me?

if i manually enter now ?p=bar to my url the string in my url is actually the default one. Because if I don't have a ?p in my url $foo = "bar";

I wonder if that's the case i can get totally get rid of the ?p= part in my url? 
if the default string is set to my $foo variable i just wanna have a clean url without any distractign ?p=bar in my url.

sorry for the weird foo and bar stuff, i had no better example ;)
regards matt

Comment: how come you have no better example? don't you have your site in real?

Comment: you have to re-ask this question, phrased clearly and with real world examle

Comment: There are all sorts of things wrong with what you just said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_GET['p'] == 'bar') {
        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $q);
        unset($q['p']);
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ($q ? "?" . http_build_query($q) : ''));
}
```

is a neat way. It does not wipe other GET parameters, if they exist.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're asking for? (Do a redirect if the default was entered)

```
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
  if ($_GET['p'] == $defaultP) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
    header("Location: ".$urlWithoutQuery);
    exit(); // or whatever the function is.
  } else {
    $foo = $_GET['p'];
  }
} else {
  $foo = $defaultP;
}
```

Note that this must be done before anything at all is sent to the client (as it's part of the header).

As far as I know, the only way to scrub something from the URL on clientside is either a redirect, or javascript (which, in effect, also does a reload, so the redirect is probably a lot faster).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this mod_rewrite tutorial:
[tutorial](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls)

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache's mod_rewrite to change example.com/?p=pagename to example.com/pagename

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Voila, no ?p=

Comment: why special rule for the favicon.ico?

Comment: if i set that, it means that i can call just mydomain.com/pagename and it actually fires mydomain.com?p=pagename is that right?

Comment: @mathiregister this is not actually answer to your question

Comment: @mathisegister that's right, so then it's up to your script to load a default page when no page is specified

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement friendly/clean urls, you might want to take a look at [Net_URL_Mapper](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL_Mapper).

Answer (score 0):

> if that's the case i can get totally get rid of the ?p= part in my url?

Yes. Just get rid of it. It's nobody but you who set these urls on your site. So, edit your site's HTML and get rid of anything you want.