# Replace ID in URL to username

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URl

> http://website.com/view/b2c32b2c782f65be2c299f7b38189a120fd51c89/

which directs the users to a profile, i.e. the id relating to the user.

Is there anyway using php/.htacess/mysql to replace this id with the relative username?

Is there any form of solution?

I use a rewrite rule so that the id in the URL is interpreted by as a get value:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([a-f0-9]{40})/$ ./view/index.php?profile_id=$1
```

Comment: Yes, but we need to see more. What script generates this URI? show us some code dude

Comment: sure. just have whatever script is handling the request look up the username and redirect to a new url based on that username.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I just need to replace the id with the username, i store the username in the same table as the id, I use the ID to retreive data about the user i.e. to generate their profile.

Comment: We use ID's because they are unique, names are not, so how will you handle 2 different ID's with the same name ?

Comment: I see what you mean, but facebook achieve this for e.g. https://www.facebook.com/'UsernameHere', I want to achieve the same trait, as it gives a URL more of an meaningful identity, if there is a solution to this, i'll implement validation to acquire unique usernames

Comment: @Chris lol so you have the solution ? add a column "pseudonym" make it unique and use a second RewriteRule ?

Comment: and for the person who tried to close the question, how is this not a question?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV no I havn't got a solution, the example above, facebook achieve this, that is what I want, what would be the second rewrite rule?

Comment: @Chris Just a question, is the id a number or in a HEX format ?

Comment: No response ? Well if you could change the profile id to only numbers, and create unique usernames with only numbers and letters you could do the following: `RewriteRule ^view/(\d+)/$ ./view/index.php?profile_id=$1` second line: `RewriteRule ^view/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ ./view/index.php?profile_id=$1`. When you use `$_GET['profile_id']` make sure to check if it's a number or numbers+letters. If it's a number query the DB for the ID if it's numbers+letters query the DB for unique username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should consider using **[RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html%E2%80%8E)** to solve your problem.

Think of this scenario: An end-user requests `view/joe-soap/`. RewriteMap would ask the server for the ID of this user, and actually request `/view/b2c32b2c782f65be2c299f7b38189a120fd51c89/`, based on the response.

For this to work, you would need to create a PHP script that accepts the user's name from the URL (as provided by RewriteMap) and then returns the ID of that user. RewriteMap would then allow you to silently request `view/index.php?profile_id=<retrieved_use_id_here>`.

I suggest that you [read through the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html%E2%80%8E) provided by Apache's website. Here are some more sites that could help you:

1. [Making sense of Rewritemaps in Apache](http://chrisadams.me.uk/2010/05/24/making-sense-of-rewritemaps-in-apache/)
2. [mod_rewrite with RewriteMap: External Rewriting Program](http://www.kuplen.at/2009/04/mod_rewrite-with-rewritemap-external-rewriting-program/)
3. [RewriteMap PRG By Example Using PHP For Apache Mod_Rewrite](http://phpsmd.blogspot.com/2008/09/rewritemap-prg-by-example-using-php-for.html)

**However**: I suggest that, considering that this adds an additional request, you simply use PHP to obtain the ID, and, within in the same request, continue from there (as others have suggested).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `GET` variables. www.mywebsite.com/view.php?username=john101

like this...

PHP (view.php)

```
<?php
  $username = $_GET["username"];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username = '".$username."'";
  //do whatever you need to do with $username and $query to create user's profile page
?>
```

I am assuming that multiple users can't have the same username.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to be able to just replace the id with a username

Comment: Sorry, other then adding `GET` variables to the URL I don't know how to change the URL. Best of luck though.

Comment: Your solution is what I'm doing now, getting the id, and querying the database to get a users information.

Comment: I don't know if you can change the variable in the URL but you could try removing the `GET` variables so that URL is clean. Here this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343057/php-getting-rid-of-p-query-in-url

Comment: what about - getting the user to go through a 'select username' process, where they basically just replace the id with a unique set of characters i.e. their unique username?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify whatever code generates the profile URIs and add the username to it. So the end result is either one of these.

> http://website.com/view/your-username/b2c32b2c782f65be2c299f7b38189a120fd51c89/
>   http://website.com/view/your-username/

That's the only way I can think of that won't require you to query the database every time someone clicks the URI. You'll have to share the code that generates the profile URIs if you want me to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Given an original URL like:

```
http://website.com/view/b2c32b2c782f65be2c299f7b38189a120fd51c89/
```

You could instead link to something like:

```
http://website.com/view/b2c32b2c78/your-username/
```

And use a RewriteRule like:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([a-f0-9]{10})/(.*)$ ./view/index.php?profile_id=$1
```

This allows for **anything** to be behind the ID portion of the url without it interfering with the ID itself.

You could then use a mysql query to select the proper user, even with just the first ten characters of their id:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE LEFT(user_id,10)='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['profile_id']) . "' LIMIT 0, 1;
```

I use this method on one of my sites which has entries upwards of three to four thousand and have yet to have any collisions just using **eight** characters, instead of the ten I used here, and have yet to see any sort of collisions.